# How to highlight gridview column where date older than

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview that is linked to a datasource.  I have a column called patched_date.

How do I highlight that column where the date is older than 30 days, 60 days, etc.

I'm not a coder.  I did find somethings similar, but I dont understand it.  Is there a different code that I can use?

Ok, I can't figure this out.  Why am i getting "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." when editing the date column?  I'm guessing it has something to do with the way it interprets the data?

How can I fix this?

```
    protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DateTime date_patched = Convert.ToDateTime(GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text);
        if (date_patched < DateTime.Now)
        {
            GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Its good idea. You can use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        //Loop throught your number of rows from gridview data
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //Datetime from your gridview column no.4 (0,1,2,3)
            DateTime date_patched = Convert.ToDateTime(GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text);

            //Here you need to modify
            //if date_patched older than 30 days and later than 60 days
             if(date_patched < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30) && date_patched > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-60)) 
             { 

                 //do something
                 GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
             }
             //if older than 60days 
             else if (date_patched < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-60))     
             {
                 //do something
             }
        }
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: means u point wrong columns
modify this yourself.
 DateTime date_patched = Convert.ToDateTime(GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text);

Comment: That should be the right column.  It is the date_patched column.  I have 7 columns.  I counted from index 0 and 3 is the date_patched.  I tried the other columns as well, and one of the error was:  The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0

Comment: try to debug and fix this "Convert.ToDateTime(GridView2.Rows[i].Cells[3].Text); "

Comment: So, i decided to give Patched_Date column a default date.  However, when I go to edit that column in gridview, its throwing the same error.  Any idea why?

Comment: you have to consider about the date time format also.